# Find out only the ids that have no children ORDER BY parents and grandparents

Tags: php, mysql

table name : level

```
+-----+-------------------+----------+
| id  | name              | parentid |
+-----+-------------------+----------+
| 1   |  AIR CONDITIONER  |  0       |
| 2   |  TV               |  0       |
| 3   |  SPLIT TYPE       |  1       |
| 4   |  WINDOWS TYPE     |  1       |
| 5   |  LCD              |  2       |
| 6   |  PLASMA           |  2       |
| 7   |  MUSIC PLAYER     |  0       |
| 8   |  AC 0.75 TON      |  3       |
| 9   |  AC 1 TON         |  3       |
| 10  |  WT 0.75 TON      |  4       |
| 11  |  WT 1 TON         |  4       |
| 12  |  LCD 32" UP       |  5       |
| 13  |  LCD 4" UP        |  5       |
| 14  |  PHOTO ALBUMS     |  0       |
| 15  |  STANDUP TYPE     |  1       |
| 16  |  CD PLAYERS       |  7       |
| 17  |  MP3 PLAYERS      |  7       |
| 18  |  CDS              |  0       |
| 19  |  BOOKS            |  0       |
| 20  |  PORTABLE TV      |  2       |
+-----+-------------------+----------+
```

So first, I tired to find out all the ids that has no children with the following query:

```
SELECT
        t1.id,
        t1.name AS name,
        t2.id AS parentid,
        t2.name AS parent_name,
        t3.id AS grandparentid,
        t3.name AS grandparent_name
FROM level t1
        LEFT JOIN level t2 ON t1.parentid=t2.id
        LEFT JOIN level t3 ON t2.parentid=t3.id
        WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT parentid from level)
```

And get the following result

```
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------------+
| id  |    name      | parent_name    | grandparent_name  |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  6  | PLASMA       | TV             | NULL              |
|  8  | AC 0.75 TON  | SPLIT TYPE     | AIR CONDITIONER   |
|  9  | AC 1 TON     | SPLIT TYPE     | AIR CONDITIONER   |
| 10  | WT 0.75 TON  | WINDOWS TYPE   | AIR CONDITIONER   |
| 11  | AC 1 TON     | WINDOWS TYPE   | AIR CONDITIONER   |
| 12  | LCD 32" UP   | LCD            | TV                |
| 13  | LCD 42" UP   | LCD            | TV                |
| 14  | PHOTO ALBUM  | NULL           | NULL              |
| 15  | STANDUP TYPE | AIR CONDITIONER| NULL              |
| 16  | CD PLAYERS   | MUSIC PLAYER   | NULL              |
| 17  | MP3 PLAYERS  | MUSIC PLAYER   | NULL              |
| 18  | CDS          | NULL           | NULL              |
| 19  | BOOKS        | NULL           | NULL              |
| 19  | BOOKS        | NULL           | NULL              |
+-----+--------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

This gets only the ids that have no children record
But I need to create an option select menu which is more user friendly like this:

I have tried ORDER BY t2.parentid DESC, t1.prentid DESC but didn't get the way I wanted

**EXAMPLE (you can ignore this sample. Just to give an idea what I need to achieve):**

```
<option>Air Conditioner >> STANDUP TYPE</option>
<option>Air Conditioner >> SPLIT TYPE >> AC 0.75 TON</option>
<option>Air Conditioner >> SPLIT TYPE >> AC 1 TON</option>
<option>Air Conditioner >> WINDOWS TYPE >> AC 0.75 TON</option>
<option>Air Conditioner >> WINDOWS TYPE >> AC 1 TON</option>
<option>BOOKS</option>
<option>CDS</option>
<option>MUSIC PLAYERS >> MP3 PLAYERS</option>
<option>MUSIC PLAYERS >> CDS PLAYERS</option>
<option>PHOTO ALBUM</option>
<option>TV >> LCD >> LCD 32" UP</option>
<option>TV >> LCD >> LCD 42" UP</option>
<option>TV >> PLASMA</option>
<option>TV >> PORTABLE TV</option>
```

So I need to figure out a different query:

EXPECT RESULT

```
+-----+-------------------+------------------+--------------+
| id  | grandparent_name  | parent_name      |    name      |
+-----+-------------------+------------------+--------------+
| 15  | NULL              | AIR CONDITIONER  | STANDUP TYPE |
|  8  | AIR CONDITIONER   | SPLIT TYPE       | AC 0.75 TON  |
|  9  | AIR CONDITIONER   | SPLIT TYPE       | AC 1 TON     |
| 10  | AIR CONDITIONER   | WINDOWS TYPE     | WT 0.75 TON  |
| 11  | AIR CONDITIONER   | WINDOWS TYPE     | AC 1 TON     |
| 19  | NULL              | NULL             | BOOKS        |
| 18  | NULL              | NULL             | CDS          |
| 16  | NULL              | MUSIC PLAYERS    | CD PLAYERS   |
| 17  | NULL              | MUSIC PLAYERS    | MP3 PLAYERS  |
| 14  | NULL              | NULL             | PHOTO ALBUM  |
| 12  | TV                | LCD              | LCD 32" UP   |
| 13  | TV                | LCD              | LCD 42" UP   |
|  6  | NULL              | TV               | PLASMA       |
| 20  | NULL              | TV               | PORTABLE TV  |
+-----+-------------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Is this achievable?
Can I use **CASE WHEN** and how?

Or do I have to use php to re-order the result?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is slightly different result than you wanted, but i think itis what you really want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN l3.id IS NOT NULL THEN l3.id WHEN l2.id IS NOT NULL THEN l2.id ELSE l1.id END) as last_level_id, l1.name, l2.name, l3.name
FROM level l1
LEFT JOIN level l2 on l2.parentid = l1.id
LEFT JOIN level l3 on l3.parentid = l2.id
WHERE l1.parentid = 0
ORDER BY l1.id, l2.id, l3.id
```

Comment: Yes, I think can go from there!